# Are there any soup kitchens or food pantries in Tromsø?

Tags: budget, food-and-drink, norway, tromso, norwegian-citizens

I'm in Tromsø, Norway and due to some very unusual circumstances I'm down to my last dime, but my flight to Oslo is not until a few days from now. So I wonder if there's any soup kitchens, or free food services, or food pantries in Tromsø (I *am* a Norwegian resident).

The closest thing I could find was [Tromsø Folkekjøkken](https://www.facebook.com/Troms%C3%B8-Folkekj%C3%B8kken-Peoples-Kitchen-Troms%C3%B8-843690995660254/) but they do not have events every day.

Comment: Real Norwegians don't buy food, they "harvest" it directly from the mountains (berries, fish, meat) ;-)

Comment: could you come back and reassure us you're still alive?

Answer (score 6):

You could try the Frelsesarmeen Tromsø (Salvation Army), Grønnegata 97, 9259 Tromsø, Tel 77 68 31 82, www.frelsesarmeen.no/tromsoe